# UIPageControl lagging on retina devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipagecontrol

I've implemented an iphone app with a page controller following Apple's code example. There are only 3 views on the page controller. The app works fine on normal screens, but when I test it on retina devices, there is a visible lag when scrolling either horizontally or vertically in any of the views. Any ideas of what the problem might be or how can I "debug" this?

The content of 2 of the views is a table view and on the third view I'm using CorePlot. The network is not used while scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was adding a shadow around the 3 views and that's what was making the scrolling slow.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data loaded and drawn during the scroll makes your device choking. Try to load those views in other thread using gcd and blocks.

Comment: Even with the vertical scrolling for a table view?

Comment: Besides, it only lags on retina devices, which makes me think that's not the problem.

Comment: This proves my thesis, as retina needs 4 times bigger memory flow to display whole screen. If you can do measurement, you may find delays around this number according to those on normal screen